# F# coding style and standard

Tags: f#, coding-style

While there is no One True Correct Style, some points of general agreement exist in the C# community regarding coding standard / style; usually, they are variations of the .NET Framework Design Guidelines.

When you look into F#, though, the standard is visibly different from what is considered normal in C#. As an example, the functions accessible on List or Seq (almost) all start in lower case: List.fold, List.map (but List.Cons and List.Empty don't...), whereas it is usually accepted that a method or property in C# should be capitalized.

So my question is, **are there widely accepted coding conventions for F#? Is there an equivalent to the Framework Design Guidelines, or a good coding standard** out there? And, as a bonus, in the whitespace-based F# world, do people have topics to argue endlessly about, similar to the timeless C# curly-brace position?

Comment: List.Cons and List.Empty are constructors, not functions. That's why they start with capital letters.

Comment: I understand the distinction; however, I would like to know if this kind of accepted convention is written somewhere. In C#, both methods and constructors start with a capital.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The F# team has drafted a document that sounds like exactly what you're asking for.  (We're currently in the process of incorporating feedback from community/insiders we've sent the draft to.)  It is likely to be published in the near future.  I'll be sure to link it here when it's published.

EDIT

[The document is archived now](http://web.archive.org/web/20110805104847/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) and you should [consult the updated version](https://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/fsharp-design-guidelines-v14.pdf) instead.

There's also a section of the MS docs that's derived from itL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines

Comment: Very cool. The lack of a standard is not my biggest problem by a long stretch, but I really like consistency, and this would help. Any thoughts on having something like StyleCop for F#?

Comment: I don't personally have any thoughts, and I am not aware of anyone planning to create such a tool.  (You could create it and become important to the F# community! :) )

Comment: I think that most of the coding conventions comes from the OCaml background.

Answer (score 7):

*Update #2:  There is now an [F# Style Guide on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/).  This contains new material and also incorporates the material I linked to in Update #1 below.*

*Update #1:  Don's paper (linked below) has been removed from the Microsoft site.  However, [A comprehensive guide to F# Formatting Conventions](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md) appears to be based on the same paper.*

Don Syme's [F# Coding Guidelines paper](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/expert-fsharp-draft/FormattingConventions.doc) deals with the "curly-brace" formatting style issues for F#.